# WordPress redirects me to posts page after editing one page

Tags: pages

I'm looking for some help on this since it has just started happening for no apparent reason. Recently, when I have been making an edit to my 'Teams' page on my site, the **Preview** and **Update** buttons both redirect me to the Posts page on my dashboard. The edits I had just previously made are also unsaved when I go and check back. I am able to make edits on the rest of my pages but for some reason this single one is giving me issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Block Editor or Classic? Any plugins that would affect this particular page vs. others? Any console errors?

Comment: @WebElaine I'm currently using the WPBakery Page Builder, and that seems to be the only plugin affecting this page. There are also no console errors that I could come across. I was hoping to test each plugin by deactivating one at a time, but I'm worried that might affect the current content on my site.

Comment: Yes, WPBakery is one of the few plugins where if you deactivate it you may lose content. I would recommend contacting their support team for help. Alternatively, during a low-traffic time, you could back up the whole site (files, database, and all), go ahead and deactivate plugins, then open a new Incognito window (or clear your whole browser cache) to test whether the problem still exists on that page. You could then restore your backup to be sure all settings are exactly as they were, and you would know if a plugin is at fault.